# Kivy StackLayout in ScrollView

Tags: python, scrollview, kivy

I Just cant get it to scroll....

heres my code:

```
    sview=uix.scrollview.ScrollView(size_hint=[1,2],scroll_type=['bars','content'],valign='top',bar_width="10dp")
    bl=uix.stacklayout.StackLayout(size_hint_y=None)
    for x in list:
        bl.add_widget(uix.button.Button(text=x['text'])

    sview.add_widget(bl)
```

Its a little bit more complex but thats the gist of it

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working example of scrollview. From the docs: [ScrollView](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html#managing-the-content-size-and-position)
I edited it to use stacklayout.

Try change size_hint in ScrollView, like this:
`size_hint=(1, None)`

Also set the size of the ScrollView so it has the windows height:
`size=(Window.width, Window.height)`

And as in the example, bind the layouts minimum height. Add `bl.bind(minimum_height=bl.setter('height'))` in your case.

And at last set the size_hint of the button to None:
`size_hint_y=None`

```py
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.app import runTouchApp

layout = StackLayout(size_hint_y=None)
# Make sure the height is such that there is something to scroll.
layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
for i in range(100):
    btn = Button(text=str(i), size_hint_y=None, height=40)
    layout.add_widget(btn)
root = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height))
root.add_widget(layout)

runTouchApp(root)
```

If you want to change the window size, try making it in kv lang. That way it automatically binds to Windows size.
Like this:

```
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App


KV = '''

#: import Window kivy.core.window.Window

ScrollView:
    size_hint: (1,None)
    size: (Window.width, Window.height)
    MyLayout:

'''


class MyLayout(StackLayout):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyLayout,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint_y=(None)
        self.bind(minimum_height=self.setter('height'))
        for i in range(100):
            btn = Button(text=str(i), size_hint_y=None, height=40)
            self.add_widget(btn)


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):    
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks that seems wo work, but my method of changing the default window size doesnt work once I import Window. How do I change the window size?

Comment: Got it, but that only seems to work with the default Window size (and my ScrollView cannot cover the whole window). Once I change the size per Window.size its not working anymore?

Comment: @Bohr you are wellcome

Comment: If the `ScrollView` is inside another widget, you can replace `size: (Window.width, Window.height)` with `size: (self.parent.width, self.parent.height)` to only use your allotted area.